# Small issue with IF.. OR statement on PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to Validate email twice on a registration form, in order to do it i'm trying to first check that the actual email field isn't empty by running the "empty" function or both of the fields - but for some reason it wont accept it, it complains about unexpected '('

here's the line:

```
if (empty(($_POST['e-mail']) OR ($_POST['e-mail2']))) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
}
```

anyone has an idea why i'm getting it and how to fix it ?

Comment: You have a syntax error with your parenthetical and logic (see below). Also be aware that `filter_var($_POST['e-mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` exists and should be used as well.

Comment: Note, you can't use `empty($var || $var)`. As I noted, used `filter_var`.

Comment: Demo of [`empty($var || $var2)`](https://ignite.io/code/511f85acec221ea011000000) (hit the play `>` button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if (empty($_POST['e-mail']) || empty($_POST['e-mail2'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
}
```

You might also want to include the [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function to make sure the POST key is actually set before checking for a value.

---

**Edit**

Just for clarity, I'll post an edit here. If you want to validate both the existence of a value, and whether one value for an input equals another, you need to do two sanity checks:

```
// Check existence of values
if (empty($_POST['e-mail']) || empty($_POST['e-mail2'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
}

// Check equivalence
if ($_POST['e-mail'] != $_POST['e-mail2']) {
    $error[] = 'Your e-mails do not match';
}
```

Comment: This is a syntax issue - I haven't seen the structure of his form. As far as I'm concerned, he may well have two email input fields.

Comment: `e-mail` and `e-mail2` (**2**). The OP was trying to do the `empty` logical on both all at once with an `OR`. That's the problem, so leaving `empty` off the latter is not quite right. (Not my downvote.)

Comment: @AmitSonnenschein Why do you want to check if its empty twice? Your question's quite confusing...

Comment: both suggestions are wrong. `||` is no better than `OR` here and isset() also useless in this case.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I never said `||` is 'better' than `OR` - it's my preferred syntax. I suggested `isset()` to avoid any future issues with his form validation checks.

Comment: @Hohner as i'm not sure what would be the best approach to validating the two fields i first want to check if any of their is empty (and post related error msg) and then if check if both of them match (and if not to post related error msg).

Comment: @AmitSonnenschein - You could accomplish the same thing with `!$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['email2']`. Practically, whether it's empty or doesn't match can (should?) be communicated at once, *Your email must be provided and must match.* `filter_var_array(array($_POST['email'], $_POST['email2']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` might also work as a check on both (values will be empty if invalid).

Comment: Note, @hohner, if both are empty... Matching isn't the only concern.

Comment: @AmitSonnenschein I agree with Jared: using PHP filters is a great idea because it can save you a lot of hassle and time (your validation will also be a lot more watertight and DRY).

Comment: @AmitSonnenschein - Here is example output from multiple checks with `filter_var_array`: https://ignite.io/code/511f894dec221e362d000000 (Hit the `>` play button top, left.) Do that first into a variable, then logically check if either array item is empty or doesn't equal, and that would give you what you want, and validate the email at the same time.

Comment: @AmitSonnenschein, actually... You really only need `filter_var` on `e-mail`, THEN check if IT is empty OR non-equal to `e-mail2`. `e-mail2` only matters if `e-mail` is non-empty and valid, per se.

Comment: @AmitSonnenschein - More demos: https://ignite.io/code/511f8bf8ec221e7f21000000 You want `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing logical expression to empty(), which is obviously wrong
you need to check both variables separately

```
if (empty($_POST['e-mail']) OR empty($_POST['e-mail2'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You meant:

```
if (empty($_POST['e-mail']) OR empty($_POST['e-mail2']))
```

PHP cannot guess that, it just evaluates your expression like that:

```
if (empty(($_POST['e-mail']) OR ($_POST['e-mail2'])))
if (empty('value_of_email1'  OR 'value_of_email1'  ))
if (empty(                  true                   ))
if (                        false                   )
```

if **one** of the submitted values is *truthish* (i.e. not-empty), the OR expression still evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use logical expression within an `empty()` method. 
Try separating logical expression to two separate `empty()` method calls.

Try:

```
if (empty($_POST['e-mail']) OR empty($_POST['e-mail2'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
}
```

For more information on `empty()`, take a look at [PHP manual on empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Answer (score 0):

For posterity...

```
$email1 = filter_var('aaa@email.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$email2 = filter_var('aaa@email.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$unmatched1 = filter_var('aaa@emil.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$unmatched2 = filter_var('aab@email.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$invalid1 = filter_var('aaa.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$invalid2 = filter_var('email.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$empty = filter_var('', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

var_dump(!$email1 || $email1 !== $email2);
var_dump(!$email1 || $email1 !== $unmatched2);
var_dump(!$unmatched1 || $unmatched1 !== $email2);
var_dump(!$email1 || $email1 !== $invalid2);
var_dump(!$invalid1 || $invalid1 !== $email2);
var_dump(!$email1 || $email1 !== $empty);
var_dump(!$empty || $empty !== $email2);
```

Gives:

```
bool(false) // Desired in validation...
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

https://ignite.io/code/511f8bf8ec221e7f21000000

So if you replace `var_dump` with `if` and simplify `e-mail2` (no need to validate):

```
$email = filter_var($_POST['e-mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if (!$email || $email !== $_POST['e-mail2']) {
    // error stuff, including separate check on empty.
}
```